# Sikuli integration with Selenium WebDriver

Tags: testing, selenium-webdriver, automation, sikuli

Can anyone tell me how to work with multiple edit boxes using Sikuli integrated Selenium WebDriver.

For example, I have 2 edit boxes which are labeled as username and password. So I want to click on the 1st edit box, then enter values and again want to click on the 2nd edit box. The size of the two edit boxes are the same. So how *sikuli integrated Selenium WebDriver* will identify which edit box to click.

Comment: If the ID or Name of that 2 boxes are different you can use Selenium WebDriver. You can locate the each element by different ID, Name or XPath

Answer (score 1):

If you are referring to the SikuliWebDriver, then this link has an example on the usage   http://code.google.com/p/sikuli-api/wiki/SikuliWebDriver.

I would rather prefer using the Sikuli Java API and create wrapper functions around the Sikuli functions like click, type etc. This API is in active development and has good support available.
http://doc.sikuli.org/faq/030-java-dev.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use the offset functionality. ie, you do not only use an image of the text field, but use a region of the screen which identifies something related to the text fields.

You may select a large rectangle which includes a heading above both fields, then use offset x/y coordinates and move the little crosshair over the exact location you wish to click/type.

[image: Sikuli Offset]